I made an old CodeIgniter 2 PHP 5.6 website over 10 years ago, and am trying to restore it online; keep getting 404 errors (the first page works, tho)
I keep getting server 404 errors when trying to interact with my website: http://www.interjo.in/
my .htaccess file is as follows:
RewriteEngine On
# First add the www to URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^interjo.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.interjo.in/$1 [L,R=301]

# The remove the index.php from URL
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|ref_doc|media|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

in my config file, these are the first few options:
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| If this is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the protocol, domain and
| path to your installation.
|
*/
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.interjo.in/';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI PROTOCOL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
| URI string.  The default setting of 'AUTO' works for most servers.
| If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
|
| 'AUTO'            Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
|
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URL suffix
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to add a suffix to all URLs generated by CodeIgniter.
| For more information please see the user guide:
|
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
*/

$config['url_suffix'] = '';

For some reason the signup page is only showing up if i add /index.php?/signup at the end see here:
https://www.interjo.in/index.php?/signup
but if i type it WITHOUT the index.php, it shows a 404 error code, like this:
https://www.interjo.in/signup
i dont understand why it's doing that; shouldnt codeigniter 2 figure out that im calling the "signup" controller without the extra /inedx.php?/?
i'm hosting this on my synology NAS via docker (via web station and container manager)

It looks like your RewriteRule is not working.
To check it, try changing index.php/$1 to test.php/$1, add a file named test.php containing <?php echo 'in test.php';.
If you open https://www.interjo.in/signup and do not see 'in test.php' then it proves that these is something wrong with your Apache config or .htaccess .
If it does work, then your problem is somewhere else.

i still get a 404 error not found. i must note that i'm hosting this on a Synology NAS using Container Manager (Docker) and Web Station, so im not sure if that affects anything.
